# Grunt ngconstant: generation from multiple exchangeable files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gruntjs

In an angular project started with `Yeoman`, we have json files (dev, test, dist...) with the constants needed for each environment to work so that the grunt serve task is defined like:

```
grunt.registerTask('serve', function(environment) {
  grunt.task.run([
    ...
    'ngconstant:'+environment,
    ...
  ]);
});
```

and then in ngconstant we have:

```
ngconstant: {
  options: {
    name: 'environment',
    dest: ...
  },
  dev: {
    constants: {
      'ENV': grunt.file.readJSON('environments/dev.json')
    }
  },
  test: {
    constants: {
      'ENV': grunt.file.readJSON('environments/test.json')
    }
  },
  ...
  }
}
```

so that it can be run with `grunt serve:dev`, `grunt serve:test`...

Now we need to also modify certain aspects of the application depending on a second criteria (let's call it user target), in a way that it could be built like `grunt serve:dev:target1`, `grunt serve:test:target2`...

Can this be done with ngconstant? the only similar idea I had so far was to define targets like `dev-target1`, `dev-target2`, `test-target1`... where each set `ENV` to one file and `TARGET` to the other, but that's not scalable (we're working with just two targets but we expect more coming soon) and just plain ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found a way to do this.  ngconstant in the Gruntfile:

```
ngconstant: {
  dev: {
    options: {
      name: 'environment',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.app %>/js/modules/environment/config/environment.js'
    },
    constants: {
      'ENV': grunt.file.readJSON('environments/dev.json')
    }
  },
  test: {
    options: {
      name: 'environment',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.app %>/js/modules/environment/config/environment.js'
    },
    constants: {
      'ENV': grunt.file.readJSON('environments/test.json')
    }
  },
  prod: {
    options: {
      name: 'environment',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.app %>/js/modules/environment/config/environment.js'
    },
    constants: {
      'ENV': grunt.file.readJSON('environments/prod.json')
    }
  },
  local: {
    options: {
      name: 'environment',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.app %>/js/modules/environment/config/environment.js'
    },
    constants: {
      'ENV': grunt.file.readJSON('environments/local.json')
    }
  },
  superior: {
    options: {
      name: 'target',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.app %>/js/modules/target/config/target.js'
    },
    constants: {
      'TGT': grunt.file.readJSON('targets/superior.json')
    }
  },
  profesional: {
    options: {
      name: 'target',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.app %>/js/modules/target/config/target.js'
    },
    constants: {
      'TGT': grunt.file.readJSON('targets/profesional.json')
    }
  },
}
```

It's messy because everything is bundled together in the same module, but having the `serve` task defined like this:

```
  grunt.registerTask('serve', function(environment, target) {
grunt.task.run([
  ...
  'ngconstant:'+environment,
  'ngconstant:'+target,
  ...
]);
```

});

and calling it like `grunt serve:dev:superior` will first generate the `environment/config/environment.js` file with the "dev" ENV constants and then the `target/config/target.js` file with the "superior" TGT constants as defined in their respective files.

I've tried setting the same destination file for both types but the file is overwritten instead of constants being appended or anything similar.